# Nested Angular modules: Can't resolve service from npm package

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 6 app that has the following nested module structure:

```
├── node_modules/
├── package.json <- no mention of ngx-cookie-service 
└── src/
    └── app/
        ├── app.module.ts
        └── sub-module/
            ├── node_modules/
            ├── package.json <- has dependency for ngx-cookie-service
            └── sub.module.ts
```

The purpose of this structure is that the submodule can be published as an npm package and the appmodule provides a website UI for using the submodule's functions.

**I'm getting the following error when trying to run `ng build --aot` for the root project (appmodule):**

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-cookie-service/cookie- 
service/cookie.service' in 'myapp\src\app'
```

Notes:

- The erroring 3rd party npm package `ngx-cookie-service` is declared as a dependency in the package.json under `sub-module`.
- sub.module.ts is imported into the @NgModule in app.module.ts
- If I add `ngx-cookie-service` as a devDependency in the root package.json, the build succeeds
- Bulding and serving without `--aot` works perfectly

My first question is:

**Is this a problem in my configuration or is it something about which I should contact the author of `ngx-cookie-service`?**

And another folllow-up question:

**How to resolve this error without adding a dependency for `ngx-cookie-service` in the root package.json?** (Because that app doesn't itself need the cookie service, only the submodule needs it)

Comment: you can't have to node_modules in on workspace. You have to install ngx-cookie-service in your root package.json. Angular only will consider the root node_modules. I don't if it is possible to like two node_modules

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a angular workspace where you can able to create multiple libraries and Applications.
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

## Pros

- You can able to publish your library to npm
- you can share that library with your apps in a workspace.

read this post for better understanding

https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-workspace-no-application-for-you-4b451afcc2ba

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that my npm library (submodule) would have dependencies to every npm package that is required by the demo UI but not required by the library?

Comment: you can have multiple package.json file not multiple node_modules folder. The same thing is done by angular workspace. Please try some demo with above instructions. we can get some ideas